# 3D graph plotting using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, 3d

[enter image description here][1]I am working on a project, for which data was generated from a c code, which I copied in a txt file, which I have given below. I am supposed to read that data via python, hence generating a 3D graph using matplotlib. I have gone through a lot of pyhton codes, but I don't know how to figure out the x, y and z axis from the data to plot.
I know its a vague and lame question, but I  am new to this and suck at maths as well.

Data.txt

```
s1  s2  s3  s4  s5  s6  s7  s8  s9  s10 s11 s12 s13 s14 s15 s16 
64m 838.4   829.2   819.0   807.5   798.9   787.5   773.9   765.3   752.9   742.0   728.3   713.3   702.2   687.2   683.2   660.3   
32m 838.3   828.7   818.5   808.5   799.9   785.9   774.4   766.8   752.8   741.0   729.6   712.9   701.2   688.6   680.3   659.1   
16m 838.5   828.1   816.8   806.8   800.2   787.8   777.0   767.6   752.7   738.0   733.3   716.8   704.2   692.8   684.9   660.2   
8m  835.5   830.3   822.3   812.4   799.8   792.1   779.6   769.8   757.5   744.8   733.2   716.4   704.2   692.2   684.7   664.6   
4m  835.5   829.9   818.7   815.1   807.4   795.5   759.0   775.2   761.8   752.3   739.2   723.8   711.6   696.4   688.5   669.0   
2m  842.5   852.1   849.0   840.9   842.5   836.0   824.8   825.9   819.1   820.5   815.5   809.8   803.8   794.7   786.5   772.7   
1024k   855.4   855.8   854.4   851.1   853.0   851.0   848.1   831.7   843.6   842.2   841.2   839.7   836.7   830.0   822.3   812.0   
512k    855.3   856.7   854.3   851.8   853.1   849.8   848.1   845.7   843.2   842.8   841.2   840.4   836.4   831.2   821.5   812.0   
256k    853.6   854.5   825.0   831.8   851.4   846.4   846.5   843.2   842.6   841.8   842.3   843.0   845.3   847.0   839.1   829.9   
128k    854.6   853.3   853.6   851.2   852.9   852.7   846.6   845.5   843.8   843.7   847.6   849.9   853.4   855.1   853.8   844.8   
64k 854.4   854.6   854.0   849.6   853.2   851.6   847.3   844.4   841.6   843.2   847.7   846.6   847.6   847.4   848.1   841.7   
32k 855.8   859.7   857.2   857.3   856.0   861.4   859.8   859.4   861.8   854.7   852.4   852.9   854.0   847.8   844.6   846.4   
16k 857.6   860.4   851.9   850.0   850.4   846.9   857.0   845.1   838.3   841.6   838.5   844.9   837.1   847.1   839.7   829.4   
8k  851.1   850.0   843.8   869.5   840.6   832.4   848.6   829.4   839.2   829.0   811.9   833.7   823.0   810.7   810.8   821.4   
4k  851.9   856.4   833.6   828.1   818.7   814.3   822.1   808.4   819.8   784.8   773.3   769.9   766.6   771.5   752.7   765.2   
2k  867.3   830.7   810.1   810.9   794.2   777.5   758.2   768.5   739.7   726.9   719.1   718.2   699.9   700.0   672.1   685.9   
1k  832.3   807.8   794.8   774.0   726.9   712.4   687.5   687.7   721.9   726.9   703.5   695.7   692.5   662.2   537.7   667.2
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all have a look at the [docs](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#getting-started). I assume you have never plotted with matplotlib before. Let's start with how it basically works. First of all, format your data into python iterables like lists/arrays/tuples. We will also need matplotlib of course:

```
# we need this to create figures
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# this is needed for 3d projections
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# some chunks of your data as lists
x = [128e3, 64e3, 32e3, 16e3, 8e3, 4e3, 2e3, 1e3]
s1 = [854.6, 854.4, 855.8, 857.6, 851.1, 851.9, 867.3, 832.3]
s2 = [853.3, 854.6, 859.7, 860.4, 850.0, 856.4, 830.7, 807.8]
s3 = [853.6, 854.0, 857.2, 851.9, 843.8, 833.6, 810.1, 794.8]

# to plot 2d data create a figure
fig = plt.figure()
# add a (sub)plot
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
# use it to plot your 2d data
ax.plot(x, s1)
plt.show()
```

For 3d data it is basically the same:

```
fig = plt.figure()
# tell matplotlib to use 3d projection
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
# now we need 3d data of course
ax.plot(x, s1, s2)
plt.show()
```

The 3d data now is the trace of n points (x_0, s1_0, s2_0) to (x_n, s1_n, s2_n) through a 3d space. There are many ways to present your data(see the link). They all basically follow the same syntax. As an other example a 3d scatter plot:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(x, s1, s2)
plt.show()

# a bit more tricky, we will need NumPy
import numpy as np

# we want to plot three graphs
idx = np.arange(3)
# So we need a meshgrid
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, idx)
Z = np.array([s1, s2, s3])
# Basically X has now three 'lanes'
# Y has 1k to 128k for each lane
# And Z[n] has the data for lane n

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z, cstride=0)

plt.show()
```

Comment: I have copied the data, please have a look.

Comment: Impressive edit. Please post full answers only in the future, as link-only answers (such as this one before the edits) are not acceptable. See more in [answer].